# Magento Patch 7405 v1.1 update error

Tags: patches

I am running Magento version 1.9.2.0 and I am trying to install patch 7405 v1.1 with "PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.2.0_v1.1-2016-02-23-07-41-47.sh" but I am getting an error patching. Below is the error I am getting

> sh PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.2.0_v1.1-2016-02-23-07-41-47.sh
>
> Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
>
> ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
>
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
>
> Hunk #1 FAILED at 121. 1 out of 1 hunk Failed -- saving rejects to
>   file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php.rej
>
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php patching file
>
> > app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
>
> patching file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php

The previous version(7405 v1) was installed by my developer who said he never change the core file manually which I think is a lie because I checked the core file and noticed $links = array(); was added :

```
if (!empty($data) && is_array($allowedTags) && in_array('a', $allowedTags)) {
 #$links = [];
 $links = array();
 $i = 1;
 $data = str_replace('%', '%%', $data);
 $regexp = "/<a\s[^>]*href\s*?=\s*?([\"\']??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/siU";
 while (preg_match($regexp, $data, $matches)) {
 //Revert the sprintf escaping
 $url = str_replace('%%', '%', $matches[2]);
 $text = str_replace('%%', '%', $matches[3]);
 //Check for an valid url
 if ($url) {
 $urlScheme = strtolower(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME));
 if ($urlScheme !== 'http' && $urlScheme !== 'https') {
 $url = null;
 }
 }
 //Use hash tag as fallback
 if (!$url) {
 $url = '#';
 }
 //Recreate a minimalistic secure a tag
 $links[] = sprintf(
 '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
 htmlspecialchars($url, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false),
 parent::escapeHtml($text)
 );
 $data = str_replace($matches[0], '%' . $i . '$s', $data);
 ++$i;
 }
 $data = parent::escapeHtml($data, $allowedTags);
 return vsprintf($data, $links);
 }
 return parent::escapeHtml($data, $allowedTags);
 }
}
```

I have delete $links = array(); and remove # in front of the (#$links = [];) but still given the same error.

I checked app/etc/ folder for "applied.patches.list" but there is no file with that name, I noticed there is "PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.2.2_v1-2016-01-20-04-35-33.sh" in my Magento folder which I believe is the file he used to patch.
My question is can you use a patch with version 1.9.2.2 on Magento version 1.9.2.0? Do I need to download "PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.2.2_v1.1-2016-02-23-07-41-47.sh" instead of "PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.2.0_v1.1-2016-02-23-07-41-47.sh" to solve the problem?

Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometime even after you delete the line of code some spaces or other things still present, which is when magento checks for it's originality, it fails and then doesn't applies the patch.

I would recommend you to download fresh file `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php` and replace it then apply the patch.

That should fix the trouble.

**UPDATE**

To download older/your version of magento:

**Step 1**:
Go to below link

http://www.magentocommerce.com/download

And then click on Release Archives tab and here you will find old magento version

**Step 2**: You can login to magento and then go to download section, you will see available option for you. (This is for Enterprise users)

Comment: Thank you for your reply but how do I download fresh `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php file?` and do I patch with the version 1.9.2.0 or download one for version 1.9.2.2 since I believe my developer patched with `PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.2.2_v1-2016-01-20-04-35-33.sh`

Comment: https://www.magentocommerce.com/download for magento fresh file, you should install the patch that applicable to your version, if it is not applicable, then obviously magento won't allow you to install.

Comment: Ok I will download fresh Magento file then replace my `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php` file. The question I have is, since this is a fresh file from 2015 it will not have any patch applied to it so do I have to reapply SUPEE 7405 v1 then 7405 v1.1 or just apply the SUPEE 7405 v1.1 then it will be ok.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, I have just downloaded it (version 1.9.2.0). You know it only has up to SUPEE-6285  integrated in it so the file `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php` will not have 7405 v1 patched to it. Sorry what I mean is do I replace the sales.php then just patch with the 7405v1.1? Thank you

Comment: Check first if 7405 had changed the file `Sales.php`, if not you can replace, if it had then you have to make changes manually then apply 7405 v1.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. `Patch applied/reverted successfully`. last question, do I need to run any other command like the `chown -R web-server-user-name` or that is it? Thank you